# Excel - Cannot find range, Error 91

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have try to find emails from name input in the cell from a lookup table (different sheets). I try to lookup names from Cell K and out emails in R cells.
I lookup the emails from different sheets called Email.
[image]

[image]

This is my lookup table. But when I try to find using Find, I get error 91 which is object variable or with block not set which probably meand it cannot find the range from the lookup table.
This is my VBA codes for split names and Find. I would like to output ';' at the end of every names so that I can just sent auto reminder emails to all of them in the cells.

```
    Public Sub getEmails()
    Dim toNames As Range
    Set toNames = Range("K11") ' names input by user

   Dim names As Range
   Set names = Sheets("Email").Range("B2:C23") ' names range from lookup table from    different worksheet

  Dim splitNames
  splitNames = Split(toNames, ",")


  Dim selectedEmails As String
  Dim findRange As Range

For i = 0 To UBound(splitNames)
    ' find the range matching the name
   Set findRange = names.Find(What:=splitNames(i), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ' if match found, get the email and store to selected emails variable
    If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
    selectedEmails = selectedEmails & Sheets("Email").Range("C" & findRange.Row) & ";"
    End If

    Next i

    'output emails
    Range("R11") = selectedEmails
End Sub
```

Please help, I am really new to this VBA. This is my debug result

[image]

Comment: Qualify which sheet your Range refers to - change `selectedEmails = selectedEmails & Range("B" & findRange.Row) & ";"` to `selectedEmails = selectedEmails & Sheets("Email").Range("B" & findRange.Row) & ";"`  (Not the cause of your error, but will be the cause of the next question.)

Comment: Your error is due to the missing `Set` in `Set findRange = names.Find(.....`

Comment: I have no error now, Thanks. But I did not output as expected. it just output one name and not email

Comment: That's because you're only adding the name. Assuming you want it to return something like "Soong, Soong@company.com;", you would want `selectedEmails = selectedEmails & Sheets("Email").Range("B" & findRange.Row) & ", " & Sheets("Email").Range("C" & findRange.Row) & ";"` ...or if you just want their emails, just change the `.Range("B" & findRange.Row)`  to `.Range("C" & findRange.Row)`.

Comment: @gpsrosak is there a reason you are not using `VLookup` ? or `Match` ? whichever you prefer

Comment: @BruceWayne I did change to .Range("C" & findRange.Row), but it appear only the first name, I posted the debug result

Comment: @ShaiRado I want split the names and start find email one by one with ';' at the end of every name

Comment: @gpsrosak I think i understand what you are trying to achieve, see my answer below and let me know if that's what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing with your code approach of using the `Find` per user, I added a loop that starts at the first row with data in Column K, until last row with data. Per cell it checks all the users inside for their emails in the other "Email" sheet, and put's the merged emails `String` in Column K of the same row.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getEmails()

Dim names As Range, findRange As Range
Dim splitNames
Dim selectedEmails As String, i As Long, lRow As Long

Set names = Sheets("Email").Range("B2:C23") ' names range from lookup table from    different worksheet

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' loop column K untill last row with data (staring from row 2 >> modify where you data starts)
    For lRow = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
        ' fill array directly from cell
        splitNames = Split(.Range("K" & lRow), ",")

        For i = 0 To UBound(splitNames)
            ' find the range matching the name
            Set findRange = names.Find(What:=Trim(splitNames(i)), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            ' if match found, get the email and store to selected emails variable
            If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
                If selectedEmails = "" Then ' first email of this row
                    selectedEmails = findRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Else  ' add a ";" to separate email addresses 
                    selectedEmails = selectedEmails & ";" & findRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If

            End If
        Next i

        .Range("R" & lRow) = selectedEmails
        ' clrear all variables and arrays for next cycle
        Erase splitNames
        selectedEmails = ""
    Next lRow

End With

End Sub
```

Screen-shot of the result I got :

[image]

Comment: one more thing, how can I automate this? I don't have to run this everytime the cell for the name be filled in?

Comment: @gpsrosak  what do u mean by automate ? According to your post , this code needs to be run every time you change/add users

Comment: it means that when a user update the names cell, the email will be populated, I don't need to open the VBA and run from there

Comment: @gpsrosak  in any way you are running the VBA code, you just don't need to do it from the VB editor screen. You can modify your code to run on Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: I try to change at the getEmails as Worksheet_Change(ByRef Target As Range) but I get compile error.

Comment: @gpsrosak  you should open a new post, add your latest updated code, and describe what you are trying to achieve, it will allow other users (and me) to assist you

Answer (score 0):

mainly as per your screenshots, you may be after something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Sheets("Names") '<--| change it to actual name of your sheet with "names"
        For Each cell In .Range("K2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp)) '<--| loop through its column K cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
            WriteEmails cell.Value, cell.Offset(, 7) '<--| call 'WriteEmails()' passing current cell content (i.e. names) and cell to write corresponding emails to
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub


Sub WriteEmails(names As String, targetRng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim selectedEmails As String

    With Sheets("Email") '<--| reference your LookUp sheet
        With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns B and C from row 1 (headers) down to column B last not empty row
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Split(names, vbLf), Operator:=xlFilterValues  '<--| filter it on its 1st column (i.e. column B) with passed 'names' split by 'vblf'
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers
                For Each cell In .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--|loop through filtered cells in 2nd column (i.e. column "C")
                    selectedEmails = selectedEmails & cell.Value & vbLf '<--| build your emails string, delimiting them by 'vbLf'
                Next cell
                targetRng.Value = Left(selectedEmails, Len(selectedEmails) - 1) '<--| write emails string in passed range
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```